# How can i break a function when another function is executed?

Tags: javascript, html

In one of my javascript projects, I have a problem. When I execute a function and then execute another function, the first function performed is not interrupted. I have the example here below:

If a execute `Draw()` and after that, I execute the `Delete()`, the Draw function doesn't break.

```
<button class="button" onclick="Draw();">
  <img src="imgs/drawBtn.png">
</button>
<button class="button" onclick="Delete();">
  <img src="imgs/deleteBtn.png">
 </button>
```

```
// js code 

 function Draw(){
    let pixels = document.querySelectorAll(".pixel");
    let container = document.querySelector("#container");
    let pressed = false;
    let i;

        container.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
            pressed = true;
        })

        container.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
            pressed = false;
        })

        for(i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++){
            pixels[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
                if(pressed == true){
                    this.style.backgroundColor =  document.getElementById('colorp').value;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What to you mean by _doesn't break_ ? Please show the code and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Op wants the draw funtion to die wheb delete is run, so they don't run at the same time

Comment: doesnt't break is like the function doesn´t stop running

Comment: do you have the code for the Draw() function?

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded and non-preemptive. Events don't happen until functions return to the main event loop.

Comment: We have to see the JavaScript to know that you need by "break", in general so JavaScript functions just execute one time then "break" anyway, unless there is some kind of infinite loop (which doesn't allow other things to run) or some kind it recursion function chain or setTimeout chain or setInterval, we need to see the JavaScript to know what's up

Comment: So the `onclick` is not processed until after `Draw()` returns, you can't stop it early.

Comment: @GabrielBorges Don't put code in comments, click the [edit] link and add it to the question.

Comment: i will share now the code

Comment: In `Delete()` you can always use `removeEventListener` to remove the event listeners that would stop the `Draw()` function. But that will require some restructuring of the functions so that you can get the proper `removeEventListener` parameters passed.

Comment: @GabrielBorges I added another example that implements a toggler.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript functions execute on a single thread.

That means that a function cannot be stopped by another function outside of its own declaration. Once the `Draw()` function starts, there is no way to stop it using `Delete()`.

Depending on what `Draw()` does*, you could do something like this...

```js
    var isDrawing = false;

    function render() {
      document.getElementById("is-drawing").innerText = isDrawing ? "drawing!" : "not drawing!";
    }
    
    function Draw() {
      isDrawing = !isDrawing;
      render();
      console.log(isDrawing ? "drawing!" : "not drawing!");
    }

    function Delete() {
      isDrawing = false;
      render();
      console.log('deleted!');
    }
```

```html
     <button class="button" onclick="Draw();"><img src="imgs/drawBtn.png">draw toggle</button>
     <button class="button" onclick="Delete();"><img src="imgs/deleteBtn.png">delete</button>

    <div id="is-drawing"></div>
```

* it could just be an action that changes the state of what you're rendering using arguments — `"drawing"`, `"not_drawing"`, or `"deleted"`— three different states. But following, the convention of using one function to `Draw` and another to `Delete`, and assuming that those functions do what they describe...

You should consider using a state manager or a framework that has the capability of managing the state of this component https://www.javascriptstuff.com/state-managers/

Disclaimer (for the pros): I'm assuming that `Delete` is not a function inside of `Draw` and that `Draw` executes immediately (no `await`).